# Neo.ClientError.Statement.SemanticError: Cannot merge node using null property value for Id

Tags: graph, neo4j

Im using this query to create some relations , but i need to create node if it doesnt exist but the merge property creates for some and for other records it gives null on id for merge.

Basically if the record exists it should merge else it should create how do i do it?

```
MATCH (p:person{username:'abc.com'})-[hc:HAS_RELATION]->(pp:person{username:'xyz.com'}) 
    MERGE (con:ContactInfo{Id:hc.ContactInfoId})
    ON MATCH SET con.Updated=timestamp(),hc.ContactInfoId=ID(con) 
    ON CREATE SET con:PersonContact,con.Created =timestamp(),con.Id=ID(con),hc.ContactInfoId=ID(con) 
    WITH con
```

Please help

Answer (score 5):

You are doing `MERGE (con:ContactInfo{Id:hc.ContactInfoId})`, but if the `hc.ContactInfoId`is NULL, you will obtain yours error.

So this mean that you have  a relationship `HAS_RELATION` in your graph without a `ContactInfoId` property.

To avoid your error, you can use the `coalesce` function in cypher.
This function takes 2 args : if the first one is `NULL`, ten the function returns the second.

So perhaps you can use this merge : MERGE `(con:ContactInfo{Id:coalesce(hc.ContactInfoId, id(hc))})`